# Range of voltmeter

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I have understood how the range of an ammeter cannot be decreased. But I don't seem to understand how the range of a voltmeter can be decreased. Pls help.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you mean by this. One can design current and voltage meters for every thermodynamically useful range.